# How to add trick play to custom iOS video player build on top of AVPlayer to play .m3u8 files?

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer, m3u8

**Goal:**
To add youtube like preview feature when user seeks manually using the player seek bar.

[image]

From what I understand so far is that I will have to add "I-Frame only playlist" to my stream to enable trick play but I am not able to figure out how I will be using this to show the preview view on the video player?

**Other solutions I considered:**

1. **AVAssetImageGenerator**: It does not work on streams. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32230230/6529099).
   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41627034/6529099) says if my .m3u8 file contains "I-Frame only playlist", AVAssetImageGenerator will start returning the snapshot, but even if it does, generating thumbnails of a complete 1 hour video upfront is just not optimal.
2. **AVPlayerItemVideoOutput**  This also seems like a very brut force way to approach the problem as I need thumbnails of almost complete video.

**Current player implementation:**

I have added AVPlayerLayer as a sublayer to my view controller's view and added custom controls on top of it.

I am thinking of using something like this https://github.com/pbs/iframe-playlist-generator to add the I-Frame playlist.

PS: I am new to this, so if I have made any wrong assumption, please let me know.
Also, any links or references to some reading material I can use to dive in deeper are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you find a solution?