# Generation of thumbnail fails with error AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, avfoundation

I am using following code to generate a URL of remote video using AVAsset class

```
func generateThumnail(url :URL, fromTime:Float64) -> UIImage? {
    let asset :AVAsset = AVAsset(url:url)
    let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;

    let time        : CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1,30)

    do {
        let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: img)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
        return nil
    }
    return nil
}
```

If fails sometimes ore more often with following error for same video URL

> AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800

Not sure whats wrong with the above code I am new to AVAsset and related framework 
any help is appreciated

Comment: These crashes are random

Comment: To generate thumbnails on remote assets, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29432405/22147

Answer (score 0):

```
func getVideoThumbNail(_ videoName: String) -> UIImage {
    do {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(videoName))
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(2, 3), actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(ERROR_GENERATING_THUMNAIL): \(error)")
    }
    return ERROR_GENERATING_THUMNAIL
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    return paths[0] as NSString
}
```

Comment: fileURLwithPath is supposed to work on videos stored in local filesystem if i am not wrong

Comment: Yes, you're right. 
 
fileURLwithPath works on videos stored in local filessystem.

Comment: my video comes from internet

Comment: I got it, you're trying to create thumbnail from remote video. Try to create AVAsset object like this. 

var asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: "http://url")!, options: nil)

Comment: figured that out but no avail, still crashes